# Unwanted extern hard disk’s name changes

Tags: kodi, hard-drive, osmc

I try to make my external hard disk a permanant one on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. After editing the fstab file, It was working. However I don't know why but some times the hard disk which name is `DiskExt/` changes to `DiskExt_/`. The OS that is installed on the Raspberry is OSMC.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens after an unclean eject incident. If you remove the disk without unmounting it (or the disk resets due to a power outrage), its original mount point may remains busy. When the disk is later replugged (or the power is restored), it will be mounted again. Many mount scripts are instructed to pick a different name, often by adding a suffix like `_`, if the original mount point is already in use.

Comment: And how can i resolve this ?

Comment: Can you help me ?

Comment: Use UUID or PARTUUID in /etc/fstab. You can discover the values with a `sudo blkid` command. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026746/how-do-i-use-a-partuuid-in-fstab

Comment: @TomRibardiere Help you with what? Always unmount a disk before ejecting it, and get a better power supply if your disk switches off sporadically. If you get a stale mount point, reboot to free it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Dmitry Grigoryev](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/104487/113288) pointed out, this situation can happen after a disk is removed without ejecting it properly. The next time the computer boots the expected mount point cannot be created as it is still there, so a unique name is created by appending a `_`.

To fix this, go to the directory where the mount points are. For example on OMSC, it could be `/media`. If you see the two directories, run

```sh
sudo du -sh *
```

to *make sure* which directory is the old one (i.e. empty) and which is current. In the question above it would be `DiskExt`. Remove the old (not cleanly unmounted) directory – I’m specifically using `rmdir` and not `rm -rf` since the directory should be empty and you don’t want to accidentally lose data:

```sh
sudo rmdir DiskExt
sudo reboot
```

then reboot. The drive should mount as before.